# How can I execute a batch file with two parameters?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a batch file and an application developed in Delphi 7. I want to run the batch file with set two parameters on it, when clicking a button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do this with [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) as described by @Remy. However, `CreateProcess()` is not the easiest of functions to operate. For convenience you may find [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) to be a more amenable option:

```
uses
  ShellAPI;
....
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(BatchFileName), 'param1 param2', 
  nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Ultimately this will lead to the `COMSPEC` variable being read and then a call to `CreateProcess()` being made. The advantage is that you let the shell do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What exe and what about it?

Comment: +1 @DavidHeffernan would you recommend this method to execute an existing .vbs file too? or should I use Windows Script Interfaces (seems like overkill to me)?

Comment: @Sam This would work fine for a .vbs file. It might be more tricky to capture errors that the script returns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CreateProcess()` to run `"cmd.exe /C batchfilename parameters"`, where the path to cmd.exe is gotten from the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable.